# Linq Optimizing query with records not matching from another table

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, asp.net-mvc-4

I am having following query which pulls data from a table with records that should not be present in another table.

The query is working perfectly but it is taking too much time & performance is affected tremendously.

What changes can i make to this query to get better performance or should i be doing this in another way?

```
var data = (from A in ctx.tblMachine
where
     A.CompanyId == companyId &&
     A.InOutDate >= tempDt &&
     A.InOutDate <= toDate &&
!(from B in ctx.tblEntry
where
     B.CompanyId == companyId &&
     A.EmployeeId == B.EmployeeId &&
     A.InOutDate == B.EntryDate &&
     B.EntryMethod == "M"
select new
{
     B.EmployeeId
}).Contains(new { EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId })
orderby
A.EmployeeId, A.InOutDate select new
{
     A.EmployeeId,
     A.InOutDate,
     A.InOutFlag,
     A.InOutTime
}).ToList();
```

Comment: See what query this produces and profile it(try to rework it in sql to be faster, be aware clear cache). After that write the changes in linq. If this result should be represent in page use Skip Take to show only visible part of the records.

Comment: I just converted the above query in SQL Server & when i ran there it showed me results in 1 second. The same query when i am running in LINQ it is taking more than 20 minutes.

Answer (score 1):

You can try with join also instead of inner query...  You can use like this make change as per your need..

```
var data = (from A in ctx.tblMachine
        join B in ctx.tblEntry on A.EmployeeId == B.EmployeeId &&
                                    A.InOutDate == B.EntryDate &&
                                    B.CompanyId == companyId &&
                                    B.EntryMethod == "M" 
        where
                A.CompanyId == companyId &&
                A.InOutDate >= tempDt &&
                A.InOutDate <= toDate &&
                !(B.EmployeeId).Contains(new { EmployeeId = A.EmployeeId })
        orderby
        A.EmployeeId, A.InOutDate
        select new
        {
            A.EmployeeId,
            A.InOutDate,
            A.InOutFlag,
            A.InOutTime
        }).ToList();
```